# Why does this Ext.grid.Panel crash?

Tags: extjs4, gridpanel

This crashes:

```
var grdMakes = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.Panel, {
  constructor: function(paConfig) {
  }
}
```

This does not:

```
var grdMakes = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.Panel, {
}
```

The crash is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'added' of undefined
```

Why does adding a constructor cause it to crash?  I can do it with other objects like:

```
var pnlMakesMaint = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    constructor: function(paConfig) {
    }
}  // just fine
```

**EDIT**

To clarify what I want to do is that I want to be able to instantiate an object with the option to override the defaults.

```
var g = new grdMakes({});  // defaults used

var g = new grdMakes({renderTo: Ext.getBody()}); // renderTo overridden
```

This is working for everything except the `Ext.grid.Panel`

Also, I'm using `ExtJS 4`

**SOLUTION**

Turns out, extend is deprecated in ExtJS 4.  So I used this and it works:

```
Ext.define('grdMakes', {
     extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

     constructor: function(paConfig) {
        var paConfig = Ext.apply(paConfig || {}, {
           columns:   !paConfig.columns ? [{
              header: 'Makes',
              dataIndex: 'make'
           }, {
              header: 'Description',
              dataIndex: 'description'
           }]: paConfig.columns,
           height:     !paConfig.height ? 400 : paConfig.height,
           renderTo:   !paConfig.renderTo ? Ext.getBody() : paConfig.renderTo,
           store:      !paConfig.store ? stoMakes : paConfig.store,
           title:      !paConfig.title ? 'Makes' : paConfig.title,
           width:      !paConfig.width ? 600 : paConfig.width

        });

        grdMakes.superclass.constructor.call(this, paConfig);
     }
}
```

Comment: Instead of Ext.extemd you can try for Ext.override.And my doubt is what you are trying to do with constructor?I mean you want to override the base constructor or else you need to use it like methods?

Comment: same error.  I just want to be able to do things like: `var g = new grdMakes({});`  Or, be able to: `var g = new grdMakes({renderTo:Ext.getBody()})` and override the defaults

Comment: are you trying this in ExtJS3 or 4?

Comment: See edit for better clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.But your code seems like ExtJS3.Because Ext.extend is depreceated in ExtJS4 version.Instead of extend you can use define.For reference you can check the following url:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext-method-extend

Afaik,for overriding default options,this is not the perfect way.You need to use Ext.override.

For example:

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.Panel,{
   lockable : true
});
```

Like above you have to override the default options.

Comment: Ugh.  OK, I was wondering about that.  We inherited some legacy stuff here. Is there an example I can use for define?

Comment: you can check the working of define here http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext-method-define

Comment: Thanks!  I'm awarding you the answer for pointing me in the right direction.  I will update my question with my solution.